# Optimising SQL Query - ORDER BY Clause - Save previous days data in Index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, indexing, insert

We have a database with around 30 million rows (Using SQL Server). Running `SELECT` queries with an `ORDER BY` clause takes a long amount of time to complete.

This is the query:

```
SELECT Top 100 [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4],
               [Column5],[Column6],Column7],ISNULL([Column8],0),
               ISNULL([Column9],''),[Column10] 
FROM [SQLDB].[dbo].[Data] 
ORDER BY Column5 DESC;
```

There are already a few indexes on the table and I'm avoiding adding many as it is causing a conflict to the `INSERT` query that is executed occasionally.

I'm thinking of reducing the number of rows by removing old data but it's valuable content so I don't wish to remove it immediately.

Is it possible to save data in Index for a certain amount of date only? For example, store previous 10 days in Index for faster retrieval (not including current day which would consist of `INSERT` statement constantly updating the table).

How can that query be optimised to return a faster result?

Answer (score 4):

First, for your query an index on `Column5` should speed it up.  I can appreciate not wanting too many indexes.  But that is one approach.

Second, if you have a filter clause, then use it!  Even if there is no index for the `WHERE`, it will reduce the amount of space needed for the `ORDER BY`.  That is a win.

Third, you may want to look into partitioning (see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes)).  This splits one table into multiple different storage areas.  This can make queries more efficient and make it easier to drop large numbers of "old" rows.

Comment: Thank you Gordon! Helpful indeed. Can `FILTER` clause be used on SQL Server too?

Comment: @Dev . . . SQL Server does  not support `FILTER`.  I actually meant `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

Table partitioning will be your best bet if you have SQL Server 2016 SP1 (Standard or Enterprise) or Enterprise edition of SQL Server 2005 and higher.

If, however you only have a standard edition of an earlier version of SQL Server then table partitioning won’t be an option.

Standard edition of SQL Server does however support the concept of filtered indexes. You can create filtered indexes on your table that will only contain data for a fixed period interval.  Note that rolling periods such as the last 10 day is not support. You could however create a filtered index for the current month and a couple of months in the future as per following example:

```
-- Filtered index for June
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Data_Date_2017_6] ON [dbo].[Data]
(
    [Column5] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Column1],
    [Column2],
    [Column3],
    [Column4],
    [Column6],
    [Column8],
    [Column9],
    [Column10]) 
WHERE ([Column5]>='06/01/2017' AND [Column5]<'07/01/2017')
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- Filtered index for July
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Data_Date_2017_7] ON [dbo].[Data]
(
    [Column5] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Column1],
    [Column2],
    [Column3],
    [Column4],
    [Column6],
    [Column8],
    [Column9],
    [Column10]) 
WHERE ([Column5]>='07/01/2017' AND [Column5]<'08/01/2017')
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

-- Filtered index for August
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Data_Date_2017_8] ON [dbo].[Data]
(
    [Column5] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [Column1],
    [Column2],
    [Column3],
    [Column4],
    [Column6],
    [Column8],
    [Column9],
    [Column10]) 
WHERE ([Column5]>='08/01/2017' AND [Column5]<'09/01/2017')
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

In the above example, I have assumed that [Column5] is a datetime column.
The indexes created with filters in the future will be empty and SQL Server will populate them as new record that meets the filter criteria is inserted into the table. As each month progress, you can simply drop the filtered indexes for the months that is not applicable any more.  You can also create automated script than can maintain these indexes for you however, it is pretty straight forward to just manually add new months and drop old months via script as needed.
If you now include a where clause in your SQL Query to limit the result for a defined period, then SQL Server will only hit the indexes it needs as per following example:

```
DECLARE @endDateTime DATETIME = '09/01/2017'
DECLARE @startDateTime DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, -10, @endDateTime);

SELECT TOP 100 
       [Column1]
      ,[Column2]
      ,[Column3]
      ,[Column4]
      ,[Column5]
      ,[Column6]
      ,[Column8]
      ,[Column9]
      ,[Column10]
FROM  [dbo].[Data]
WHERE ([Column5]>= @startDateTime AND [Column5] < @endDateTime) 
ORDER BY [Column5] DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Note that the OPTION (RECOMPILE); clause it added to the query to force sql server to re-evaluate the query plan, this will ensure that SQL Server uses the correct index.